# Accessing dict value for item with a key that is enclosed in braces in Ansible

Tags: ansible, yaml, saml

Running into an issue accessing the value of a dict due to it having a very strange key. I used the xml module to filter through namespaces to set this object up and then set a fact equal to the value of the matches returned. If there is a better/easier way to do this I would love it because I'm stumped.

Example XML:

```
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" entityID="http://www.okta.com/id">
    <md:IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="false"
        protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>thisisfakedata</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </md:KeyDescriptor>
        <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat>
        <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</md:NameIDFormat>
        <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
            Location="https://login.company.com/app/app/id/sso/saml" />
        <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
            Location="https://login.company.com/app/app/id/sso/saml" />
    </md:IDPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

Here is my use of the namespaces and XML module:

```
- name: "Search for cert in metadata"
  xml:
    xmlstring: "{{ cert }}"
    xpath: /x:EntityDescriptor/x:IDPSSODescriptor/x:KeyDescriptor/y:KeyInfo/y:X509Data/y:X509Certificate
    namespaces:
      x: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata
      y: http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#
    content: text
  register: xml_xpath_result
```

The registered result looks something like below:

```
{
    "actions": {
        "namespaces": {
            "x": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata",
            "y": "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
        },
        "state": "present",
        "xpath": "/x:EntityDescriptor/x:IDPSSODescriptor/x:KeyDescriptor/y:KeyInfo/y:X509Data/y:X509Certificate"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "count": 1,
    "matches": [{
        "{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}X509Certificate": "thisisfakedata"
    }],
    "msg": 1,
    "xmlstring": "seexml"
}
```

If I then try to set a fact to the value of that key in the matches list it's not working. I've tried numerous ways, most recently setting a fact equal to obj.matches[0] and then trying  to just print "{{ fact.{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}X509Certificate }}" and I'm getting issues. See error below. Is there anything I can do to make this work, either with escaping they key so that it works properly or by changing up my use of the xml module in order to get a more normal key? I'm trying to avoid hacking it up more than it already feels.

```
- name: "set idp cert"
  set_fact:
    idp_app_cert: "{{ xml_xpath_result.matches[0] }}"
  when: xml_xpath_result is defined

- debug:
    msg: "{{ idp_app_cert.{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}X509Certificate }}"
```

Error:

```
TASK [pbname : debug] ********************************************************************************************************************
task path: ~tasks/main.yml:40
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: {{ idp_app_cert.{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}X509Certificate }}"}
```

For clarity, the end result here is simply to have a fact set with value: thisisfakedata

Comment: Did you tried this syntax? : {{ idp_app_cert['{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}X509Certificate'] }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got around this by accessing my key differently, and by adding single quotes around it. Leaving this up in case anybody else encounters similar..

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ idp_app_cert['{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}X509Certificate'] }}"
```

```
TASK [pbname : debug] ********************************************************************************************************************
task path: ~/tasks/main.yml:40
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "thisisfakedata"
}
```